# PHP $_SESSION values not changing

Tags: php, html

I am sending value from a send page to a receive page using sessions but i keep on getting the old sent value on the receive page despite changing the post value on the send page using php. When i tried to unset and destroy the session, it throw up an undefined error.

send page(script.php)

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!empty($_POST['recharge_no']) && !empty($_POST['recharge_mail']) && 
!empty($_POST['recharge_amt']) ){
    $mobile_no = $_POST['recharge_no'];
    $_SESSION['recharge_no'] = $mobile_no;

    $amount  = $_POST['recharge_amt'];
    $_SESSION['recharge_amt'] = $amount;

    $email = $_POST['recharge_mail'];
    $_SESSION['recharge_mail'] = $email;

    $mobile_no = $_SESSION['recharge_no'];
    $email = $_SESSION['recharge_mail'];
    $amount  = $_SESSION['recharge_amt'];

    echo 'Current user Mobile: '.$mobile_no;
    print '<br>';
    echo 'Current user Email: '.$email;
    print '<br>';
    echo 'Recharge amount: '.$amount;
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>    
<Form method="post" action="script2.php">

 <input  type="number" placeholder="Enter amount here" name="recharge_amt" 
  id="recharge_amt"/><br/>
 <br><input  type="text" placeholder="Input phone number"  
  name="recharge_no" id="recharge_no"/><br/>
 <br/><input  type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="recharge_mail" 
 id="recharge_mail" /><br/>

 <button type="submit"  value="submit">Buy</button>
</form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Recieve page(script2.php)

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['recharge_no']));{

    $mobile_no = $_SESSION['recharge_no'];
    $email = $_SESSION['recharge_mail'];
    $amount  = $_SESSION['recharge_amt'];

    echo 'Current user Mobile: '.$mobile_no;
    print '<br>';
    echo 'Current user Email: '.$email;
    print '<br>';
    echo 'Recharge amount: '.$amount;
    print  '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it going inside your if condition on receive page?

Comment: It display the value even without the if condition. The main issue i have is that when i post from sender page to reciever page i get same value posted when the session start despite changing the posted value in the send page

Comment: Why this ; is there after if condition  if (isset($_SESSION['recharge_no']));{. Just remove this

Comment: I have removed ; but it still haven't resolved the issue sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move that code to script2.php ( FORM ACTION="script2.php" )

```
if(!empty($_POST['recharge_no']) && !empty($_POST['recharge_mail']) && !empty($_POST['recharge_amt']) ){ $mobile_no = $_POST['recharge_no']; $_SESSION['recharge_no'] = $mobile_no;

$amount  = $_POST['recharge_amt'];  $_SESSION['recharge_amt'] = $amount;

$email = $_POST['recharge_mail'];  $_SESSION['recharge_mail'] = $email;
```